# Javascript doesn't work for disabled text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
  function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\Rs.|\,/g, '');
    if (isNaN(num))
      num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    if (cents < 10)
      cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
      num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num + '.' + cents);
  }
</script>
```

And I am using this script to format the currency in a text box. It is working for all enabled text boxes, but it doesn't work for disabled text boxes, as the same amount comes in text box on some event.

Below is my text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtToTSanctioned" runat="server" Text="00.00"
  CssClass="mytextbox" Enabled="False"
  onblur = "this.value=formatCurrency(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

What'd be the solution for that?

Comment: If the textbox is disabled, how would it fire the blur event?

Comment: I want to fire it on disabled mode. Is there any other solution for that, I know blur doesn't work on disabled mode.

Comment: Check my answer. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: This box is disabled on page load (`Enabled=false`), so it is never going to fire your blur code. So if you want the value to be formatted when the page is loaded, use ASP.NET to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it, is to execute it for a specific textbox. As in your case it's not enabled and value is set programmatically, you can update it value after it's populated:

```
var oldValue = $('.disabled-textbox').val();
var formattedValue = formatCurrency( oldValue );
$('.disabled-textbox').val( formattedValue );
```

Now you only need to execute this code when your textbox was populated. Also note, I used class selector `.disabled-textbox`, you may need to add this class to your textbox, or use a smarter selector to get all disabled textboxes. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/RtdsN/) that shows how to update textbox.